# popover size issue with ios 7.0.X, its not getting while loading popover

Tags: ios, ipad

My popover is not getting properly sized while presenting with ios 7.03. [image: image for ios 7.0.3]

I'm Trying like

```
{
  ...
  ClassObj *mail = [...];
  [mail.view setFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 320, 216)];
  [mail setContentSizeForViewInPopover:CGSizeMake(320,256)];
  [refinePopover presentPopoverFromRect:sender.frame inView:[sender superview]     
  permittedArrowDirections:UIPopoverArrowDirectionAny animated:YES];
  [mail setContentSizeForViewInPopover:CGSizeMake(320,256)];
  ...
}
```

And in ClassObj class i'm setting frame and size in viewwill/didApear method

```
{
  [self setContentSizeForViewInPopover:CGSizeMake(320,256)];
  [self.view setFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 320, 216)];
}
```

I'm plying more on this please let me know if you have any suggestion, Thanks in Advance. :)  [image: ios 7.1]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You create a property of `UIPopOverController` Object in your `ClassObj`

and then assign that popoverController from that class where you are creating Your actual popover.

```
mail.popoverController = refinePopover;
```

now in your ClassObj in viewwill/didApear method add this code with 0.1 delay.

```
[popoverController setPopoverContentSize:CGSizeMake(320, 256)];
```

hope this will help you.

Comment: Its wroked for me, Thanks a lot. IT seems that its hapning to older ios versions like 6.X as well. With your suggestion its works great to me... Thanks :)

Comment: As per your suggestion I implented code and works fine, Then I have tried like
    [refinePopover setPopoverContentSize:CGSizeMake(320, 256) animated:NO];
After presenting PopoverFromRect from parent class and worked :) as well so no need to create object of UIPopOverController.